# htaccess mod_rewrite to sanitize URLs

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Does anyone know a mod_rewrite rule I can add to htaccess to remove all characters from the URL EXCEPT for these characters?

A-Z, a-z, 0-9, -, ?, =, &, :, /

Comment: I just went through some .htaccess issues myself. Why do you want to remove all characters except those? What characters do you want to remove? Can you give a sample URL? Etc.

Answer (score 0):

What about this rule:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)[^A-Za-z0-9\-\?=&:/](.*)$ $1$2 [L]
```

Comment: I'll try it out tomorrow, if works will mark as right. Thanks for your fast response Kamil!

Comment: OK, just note it does internal redirect, so the address in browser will remain the same, but the request will be passed to your application w/o unwanted characters